# I want to separate field with tab delimiter and replace with comma in shell script

Tags: docker, shell, unix, awk

Shell scripting to print output with comma delimiter instead of tab delimiter for listing docker services:

```
docker ps -a | awk -F \t '{print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6","$7","$8}'
```

present output

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                              COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                          NAMES
35fe9af4efa0        thomsch98/kafdrop:latest       "/usr/local/bin/mvn-…"      3 days ago          Exited (137) 3 days ago    PAServices_kafdrop.1       x2r2tuosozdd9uzfnq7ejdi70
```

Required output,

```
CONTAINER ID,IMAGE,COMMAND,CREATED,STATUS,PORTS,NAMES
8c0e092b6815,thomsch98/kafdrop:latest,"/usr/local/bin/mvn-…",3 days ago,Up 3 days,PAServices_kafdrop.1,yen4hgju18kkfgq9bvud7e1w8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use awk and use the built in filter options of docker-ps

```
docker ps --format "{{ .Image }},{{.ID}},{{.Command}},{{.CreatedAt }},{{.Status }},{{.Ports }},{{.Names}}"
```

To retain the headers, add table:

```
docker ps --format "table {{ .Image }},{{.ID}},{{.Command}},{{.CreatedAt }},{{.Status }},{{.Ports }},{{.Names}}"
```

Comment: how to get with headers? this gives only data without header

Comment: You can retain the headers by adding "table", see the amendment above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following command:

```
docker ps -a |tr -s " "| sed 's/ /,/g'
```

tr -s will suppress multiple whitespaces to one. And sed will replace that whitespace to comma.

Comment: container ID is a single field but its is get sed spilts  into two fields. how to fix it?